# SSRS reporting. How to repeat group of rows using list control

Tags: list, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I want to be able to display a report something like:

**District1**

```
Store Name     Product      Price per piece     Quantity sold     Total Price
```

```
XYZ store     Product1              10                  6                  60
```

```
              Product2               8                  5                  40
```

**District2**

```
Store Name     Product      Price per piece     Quantity sold     Total Price
```

```
XYZ store     Product1              11                  5                  55
```

```
              Product2              10                  4                  40
```

**District3**

```
Store Name     Product      Price per piece     Quantity sold     Total Price
```

```
ABC store     Product1               10                  5                  50
```

```
              Product2               7                   8                  56
```

**District4**
**....**
**....**
**....**
**District N**

The way data is stored in database is:

```
District      StoreName       Product       Price       Qty

District1     XYZ Store       Product1      10          6

District1     XYZ Store       Product2       8          5

District2     XYZ Store       Product1       11         5

District2     XYZ Store       Product2       10         4

District3     ABC Store       Product1       10         5

District3     ABC Store       Product2       7          8
```

I tried using List control for repeating the group of rows but no luck so far. please help.

Comment: The report you are proposing is definitely suited for a table or tablix control, rather than a list control.  But for those who found this page looking for ways to group rows inside of a list control, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23016705/450750)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't use a list control. Use a Table control instead.
- Add a group (without group headers or footers) for store name.
- Add a group (with a group header) for District, as a parent group of StoreName. Delete the grouping column for District and add the District field into the group header for District, in the StoreName grouping column.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mark, I actually ended up using subreport and still using list control for repeating the subreport. I don't know if my implementation is good or bad "boss is happy now ;-)" but I will try to change it according to your suggestion soon. Thanks again.