# SSRS Group by in the List Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I am working on a SSRS Report where i have to group by the Customer Name.

Dataset will be something like this.
Select Column1, Column2,Column2 from Customer
Group by CustomerName

```
Expected Report Layout 

Customer Name :   Jim Mouse
DOB           :   12/01/1970

Column1            Column2            Column3

100                DateTwo           Some Entry
200                Assignment        Entered works
300                Freelance         Tesing 


Customer Name :   Sendil P
DOB           :   12/01/1990

Column1            Column2            Column3

100                work hard          SSRS
200                Test Zone          Earth world
```

Issue, i am facing. By placing List, on every row of record, i am getting same customer name, DOB is repeated.

```
Current Output

Customer Name :   Jim Mouse
DOB           :   12/01/1970

Column1            Column2            Column3

100                DateTwo           Some Entry

Customer Name :   Jim Mouse
DOB           :   12/01/1970

Column1            Column2            Column3
200                Assignment        Entered works

Customer Name :   Jim Mouse
DOB           :   12/01/1970

Column1            Column2            Column3
300                Freelance         Tesing
```

On following IAN steps, I attached the Image of current output.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have seen, by default a List will repeat for each row in the Dataset.

With a version of your data:

[image]

I have created a blank report with a List:

[image]

Note the three dotted lines in the List item and the Details group, indicating there is no grouping item. We want to change this to group on `Customer`:

[image]

After apply this change you can see the List and group have changed:

[image]

Now this item will repeat for each `Customer`, not each row. We can now add in the text box for `Customer`, which will show once per group, and a table, which will display all rows for that `Customer`:

[image]

Which works as required:

[image]

You can add page breaks to the group if required.

Comment: Ian, i have included the image / screen shot of my output. I followed your steps. Please help me to fix my error.

Comment: Ian , i am missing some step. I did the same as you mentioned. But i couldnt get the table of record. Please see my screenshot.

Comment: Thank you Ian Preston. It works. I have to add a Table inside the List. On doing so, it works.