# AARA grouping charts

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I am converting a chart report from Crystal to SSRS.  In Crystal the chart is in a group header, so I defined it once and for each new group.  When the report is run the chart is printed once for each group.  How do I do the same in SSRS. SSRS will not allow me to drag a field to the row groups or column groups area.  Or do I have to copy the chart for each group in the data?

Thanks in advance

Jay Tyo

Answer (score 0):

To repeat a chart for different groups, use a LIST to do the overall grouping and put your chart or table inside it.

Here I have a table of data that I wanted to break up by location.

[image]

I created a List to group by location and put the table inside. Notice the **grouping bracket** on the left side of the tables. The LIST groups everything.

[image]

You would set the list dataset to the same as your data and group on the field(s) for your grouping.

[MSDN - Lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/create-invoices-and-forms-with-lists-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)

[SSRS Group by in the List Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015511/ssrs-group-by-in-the-list-report)

[YouTube: SSRS -- Using a List Item to Display Details](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8EidVXasYg)

Comment: That was a great idea.  That got me to at least be able to create the list structure and add the grouping, but when I put the chart in details area I get a message that says "The chart has a detail member with inner members.  Detail members can only contain static inner members."

Comment: It sounds like you put the chart in a detail row rather than a grouped row in the list. Check this out: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lukaszp/2009/12/21/charts-in-a-tablix-cell-dont-work-for-me-but-ive-see-these-nice-demos-where-they-do/

Comment: Thank you very much Hannover.  Your directions along with the link in your last post solved the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, SSRS error messages are usually cryptic at best.